# выборка данных из S3 хранилища

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon, amazon-s3

есть у меня в S3 данные в виде массива, пример:

```
{
  "name": "responses",
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "znfj43yw",
      "name": "Mark",
      "link": "localhost:7777",
      "isTest": true
    },
    {
      "id": "g45h4h4f",
      "name": "Lens",
      "link": "localhost:7777",
      "isTest": true
    }
  ]
}
```

создаю таблицу:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE qq_loq (
offerrequest struct<offers:array<struct<id:string,name:string,url:string,isTest:boolean>>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('ignore.malformed.json'='true')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
          OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
          LOCATION 's3://путь/'
          TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

Делаю запрос этих данных

```
select  responses.users from  qq_loq
```

и получаю вот такое:

```
[{id=znfj43yw, name=Mark, url=localhost:7777, istest=true}, {id=g45h4h4f, name=Lens, url=localhost:7777, istest=true}]
```

**и ладно, пусть как-то живет, но как отсюда доставать сами айдишники и неймы?**

Пробовал вот так:

```
select  responses.users.id from  qq_loq
```

но тут схема явно не рабочая, потому что айдишников же несколько таких и не строка.
Так же это не JSON что бы через scalar достать, прошу хелпа у знающих людей..